# Testing Network layer encryption enabled or not

Tags: encryption, network

I am new to network security. I have a requirement to test whether the network layer encryption is enabled or not. How do I test this requirement? Are there any automated tools available?

Comment: "enabled" or "encrypted"? What sorts of test results would be acceptable? Is just looking at the network data enough or do you need a proof? Can you just looks at the protocols used or do you need to calculate the entropy of the data to prove that it is encrypted?

Comment: requirement is "Verify that network layer encryption is enabled or not"

Comment: Is this for work or for school? Do you have packet captures already or do you need to read the wire? Is the network layer IP or some other protocol?

Comment: its for work. i have to show the proofs(screenshots) how it is tested. ihave wireshark installed.

Comment: protocol information is enough

Comment: then capture packets with wireshark and inspect the packets?

Answer (score 1):

Network encryption (called also network level encryption) is a network security process that applies crypto services at the network transfer layer (above the data link level, but below the application level).

Network encryption is implemented through Internet Protocol Security (IPSec). IPSec works through the network architecture, which means that end users and applications don't need to be altered in any way.

The use of IPsec, which encrypts network traffic, renders network intrusion detection, virtually useless, unless traffic is decrypted at network layer.

To practically make a test, you could just try to send a plain text message through the network and monitor traffic to see if you can read the content or not. If you read it plainly, there is no network level encryption. If the data was received at the other end and you could not read the actual content, then there is network level encryption in-place.